# Javascript - onchange function only works once (after first change) with html select

Tags: javascript

I would like the following function to display different html inputs depending on which customer type the user has selected.

The following code only run once (when the first option is selected)

This is my html:

```
<select name="customerType" id="customerType" onchange="return customerTypeFunction()">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="nonCorp">Customer</option>
    <option value="corp">Corporate</option>
</select>

<div id="nonCorpCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename"/>
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"/>
</div>

<div id="corporateCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName"/>
</div>
```

This is my javascript function:

```
function customerTypeFunction() {

    var customerTypeSelect = document.getElementById("customerType").value;

    var corpCustomer = document.getElementById("corporateCustDetails");
    var nonCorpCustomer = document.getElementById("nonCorpCustDetails");

    if ( customerTypeSelect = 'nonCorp') {

        corpCustomer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        nonCorpCustomer.style.visibility = "visible";

    }

    if ( customerTypeSelect = 'corp' ) {

        corpCustomer.style.visibility = "visible";
        nonCorpCustomer.style.visibility = "hidden";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is assignment, `==`/`===` is comparison. Change your if statements to reflect that.

```
if (customerTypeSelect === 'nonCorp') {    
    corpCustomer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    nonCorpCustomer.style.visibility = "visible";    
}

if (customerTypeSelect === 'corp') {   
    corpCustomer.style.visibility = "visible";
    nonCorpCustomer.style.visibility = "hidden";   
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZRLP/)